# Browsing through all iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hope You all are fine..

I have a query to ask regarding new features of iPhone 4.0

My Question is .. Is there any possibility to brows any document throughout the iPhone through the application ?

I mean, Suppose in one of my application have feature to share file using Bluettoth, Now When i run this application lastly, I received one file from my Friend. and its still there.

Now i Run my Second Application and i want to access those received file in relier application here in new application.. Is there any way to implement this?

If any one have any idea, kindly guide me.

Looking Forwards,

Arun Thakkar

Answer (score 1):

From the Guidelines:

> 2.6 Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

There might be a global area where you can download and access.. I'll check